# multiple atexit handlers in different thread

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have a doubt regarding the use of `atexit` in a multithreaded application.

Suppose I have the following scenario

```
 Thread A calls atexit(handler_a)
 Thread B calls atexit(handler_b)
 main()   calls atexit(handler_main)
 Thread C calls atexit(handler_c)
 ....
```

are all the handler functions executed in a single unique thread or are they executed in separate threads?

If they do execute in a single thread (one after the other) will that thread be the main one?

I am using Linux and g++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rici says, atexit handlers are called from the thread that calls exit.  If you want per-thread handlers, you can use a pthread_key_create destructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any constraint in the standard that would require `atexit` handlers to be called from a single thread.

In fact, I believe that handlers that were registered concurrently (as in neither registration is sequenced before the other) can also be executed concurrently. The standard does however guarantee that a handler whose registration is sequenced before another will be executed after the latter.

Comment: It's hard to imagine an implementation of exit() which does not just call atexit handlers sequentially, in the thread which invoked exit().  It is true that the the standard does not define the order of atexit handlers for which the calls to atexit were not synchronized, but the standard does require atexit to be thread-safe, so it seems like there must be some order to the calls. At any rate, it is hard to see how an implementation could know whether or not two calls to atexit from different threads were deliberately synchronized.